# Node.js Automatically set current port

Tags: node.js

`require('http').createServer((req,res)=>{res.end();}).listen(80);`

`listen`
Is it possible to automatically set this to the current port?

`listen(address().port)`

do not enter port or wildcard Automatically obtain `listen(auto)` current port.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "the current port" for a server.  A server IP address can be used on a wide range of ports, there is no "current port" for an IP address.

You must specify the port you want your server to run on.  That's up to you as a developer to determine.  The most common port for an http server is port 80 and for an https server 443, but you can pick other port numbers if you have a particular reason to.

Comment: You're gonna have a rough time trying to start a server with nodejs on a port numbered < 1024 on a UNIX - based OS like Linux or MacOs: privileged ports means you must run servers as root.

Comment: @O.Jones - And, how does that change or affect the answer or the OP's question?  Zillions of https servers run on port 80 and zillions of https servers run on port 443.  If you're setting up a web server for the public, then you do what you need to do to configure it that way, either so the native server runs on the desired port or you set up port forwarding to a custom port for your server.  The point of this answer is that there is no "current port".  You have to pick the port you want/need to use and specify it.

Comment: Many apps use nginx reverse proxies in front of nodejs apps, both to terminate the TLS and to let the node app listen on a port like 3000. As I'm sure you know, but the OP may not.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to start a server with http is like this.

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.end();
})

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening... https://${hostname}:${port}/`)
})
```

You can take a look at the [doc](https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-nodejs-http-module)

Answer (score 0):

In NodeJS the `.listen(<port>, <address>, <callback>)` can accept a port number, IP address and a callback function.
However, **it is possible to call the method with no arguments at all**.
In this option NodeJS will **use a random, unused port number** on localhost address.

For example, the following block of code is valid:

```
const http = require("http");

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  console.log(req);
});

server.listen();
```

you can inspect the port and IP address of your server by writing:

```
console.log(server.address());
```

Comment: Using a random unused port number is rarely useful for a server that you expect the public to access because the client has to know what the port is.  This may be used in some programmatic circumstances where you can then query the port and then programmatically communicate that to the client or programmatically configure a proxy to forward to this port, but would not typically be used for direct access by a human client.